# how to make a Facebook server graph API call to extend Facebook token expiry from app in SDK 3.23 using Request call in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have tried this code to get the new extended Access token from Facebook server:
I am getting null pointer exception at response line and it crash my App.

```
            Bundle some = new Bundle();
            some.putString("access_token", fb_token);

            String response = facebook.request("me", some, "GET");
```

Please help me to call it to server .